# What do you call order 3 tensor-like something but doesn't have to be independent on coordinate transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, tensors, programming

What is the term used to refer multi-dimensional array of programming languages in mathematics?

I thought it was **tensor**, but I learned that tensors should obey some restrictions(indepentent on coordinate transform, ...)

For example:

A order 0 tensor is a **scalar**.

A order 1 tensor is a **vector**.

A order 2 tensor is a **matrix**.

What do you call order 3 tensor-like something but doesn't have to be independent on coordinate transformation?

Comment: It depends on what you are using it for. It could represent a function from a tuple of integers to a value.  a[1][2][3] == 15. Or it could represent a tensor. Or a million other things.

Comment: @CharlesGillingham I think I need a term of a function from a tuple of integers to a value, and used in linear-algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are misunderstanding what it means to be independent under coordinate transformations and you can call your object a rank 3 tensor, or better yet, an element of $\mathbb{R}^{n_1\times n_2 \times n_3}$.

For example, invariance under coordinate transformations does not mean that your array has to be symmetric in any way.

Invariance under coordinate transformations only makes sense in a physical context and if your array of numbers actually comes from such a context then chances are that your array is invariant without you knowing it. Without going into details, any list or array of numbers can represent a  tensor (-field, to be precise) but that depends on where they come from in your context and I don't think this discussion has anything to do with what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks! To be sure: my context is : https://mathoverflow.net/q/309449/128168 is it ok to use the term tensor?

Comment: @KYHSGeekCode I would just call them Carleman coefficients, given that the object you want to generalize are the Taylor coefficients

Comment: OK, I revised the title to "Generalization of Carleman coefficients to multivariable functions. Carleman tensor?", as I want to generalize Carleman coefficients(Generalization of Taylor coefficients is a base step).

Comment: Oh I didn't properly look at the link. Given that the Carleman matrix also exists, yes, it sounds reasonable to call your generalization the Carleman tensor

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway!

Comment: @KYHSGeekCode One final piece of advice. Don't try to name things, keep yourself busy with working things out. Who knows, if you're lucky enough people will call it the KYHS tensor. In any case, what your work or the objects used therein will be known as will be decided by mathematicians who read and discuss your work. So back to my original suggestion: Just say 'let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m\times k}$...'

Comment: Somewhat fun but also hopeful :) Thanks.